# how to change exact row/column data point in pandas for fillna

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

I want to fill nan values using some linear regression model. I use other columns that are not nan and I compute the one that is NaN.

Now, I have a problem to change the following value.

I have an array `nan_values_predicted` and the indexes of these values in the main dataset.

But I can't find a way to change the exact data point.

I tried something like:

```
df.loc[index_1]['feature_1'] = df.loc[index_1]['feature_1'].fillna(predicted_feature_1)
```

and many other variations, a bit smarter than this one but they don't work. Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough sample data to reproduce your problem. It's basically impossible to test code without sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this...

as opposed to doing `df.loc[index_1]['feature_1'] = some_value`
I should've done `df.loc[index_1, 'feature_1'] = some_value`

And everything works now